# Is it possible to see the highest voted question of the day/week?

Tags: support, voting, statistics

Is it possible to see the highest voted question of the day/week/month ?

When I look at the "votes" tab, I get a list with the all time highest voted questions. Is it possible to somehow filter this ?

Comment: If it did, wouldn't it just make the already (in many cases undeservedly) popular questions even more popular? It would be more useful to have an easy way to find good underrated questions and answers.

Comment: To narrow a search down, look for the tags "soft-question" and "reference-request."

Comment: The tabs [hot](http://math.stackexchange.com/?tab=hot), [week](http://math.stackexchange.com/?tab=week), and [month](http://math.stackexchange.com/?tab=month) serve approximately the same purpose, except that they take into account the number of answers and views, along with votes. The `hot` tab covers "a few" days rather than one day. //  You can also search for recent highly voted questions using the parameters `is:question` and `score`. Here is a [sample search query](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aquestion%20score%3a5).